# Is this proof about clock hands lining up correct?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

Is http://joshuaoldenburg.com/articles/clock-hands-line-up/ a proof? I.e. does it sufficiently prove the times where the clock hands line up?

$$
\begin{align}
H &= \text{hour (1-12)} \\
M &= 60(H-int(H)) = \text{minute (1-60)} \\
D_h &= 30H = \text{hour in degrees} \\
D_m &= 6M = \text{minute in degrees} \\
&= 6(60(H-int(H)) \\
&= 360(H-int(H)) \\\\
D_h - D_m &= 180 \\
%30H - 360(H-int(H)) &= 180 \\%
\frac{30H - 360(H-int(H))}{30} &= \frac{180}{30} \\
H - 12(H-int(H)) &= 6 \\
H - 12H + 12int(H) &= 6 \\
12int(H) - 11H &= 6 \\
12int(H) &= 11H + 6 \\
11H + 6 &= 12int(H)
\end{align}
$$

We know that at 6:00 the hour and minute hands line up, so let's plug in 6.0 for $H$.

$$
\begin{align}
11(6) + 6 &= 12int(6) \\
66 + 6 &= 12*6 \\
72 &= 72
\end{align}
$$

That works out, so we know the equation is correct. Let's try 7:00.

$$
\begin{align}
11(7) + 6 &= 12int(7) \\
77 + 6 &= 12*7 \\
83 &\ne 84
\end{align}
$$

7:00 doesn't quite work. We need one more on the left than the right. In most cases, that would be impossible, but ignore that for a minute. The left side of this equation is $11H + 6$. We want this to equal 84, so let's solve for $H$.

$$
\begin{align}
11H + 6 &= 84 \\
-6 &\hphantom{=} -6 \\
\frac{11H}{11} &= \frac{78}{11} \\\\
H &= \frac{78}{11} = 7{\frac1{11}} \\\\
11 * 7{\frac1{11}} + 6 &= 12int(7{\frac1{11}}) \\
78 + 6 &= 12 * 7 \\
84 &= 84
\end{align}
$$

$7{\frac1{11}} = 7.\overline{09} \approx 7 \text{ hours, } 5.5 \text{ minutes}$, so at about 7:05 the hour and minute hands are 180° apart. There is $1{\frac1{11}}$ hours between these two times where the hands line up, so it is a reasonable assumption that every $1{\frac1{11}}$ hours the hands line up.

$$
\begin{align}
7{\frac1{11}} + 1{\frac1{11}} &= 8{\frac2{11}} \\\\
+ 1{\frac1{11}} &= 9{\frac{3}{11}} \\
\cdots \\
+ 1{\frac1{11}} &= 17{\frac{11}{11}} = 18
\end{align}
$$

At this point, we've gone until we hit a whole number. Most of these times, though, are after 12 o'clock. In these cases, we can apply the modulus function, $mod$. This gives us the remainder after dividing. For example, $13 \bmod 12 = 1$. We stopped adding at the whole number 18. $18 \bmod 12 = 6$, so we looped back around to six o'clock. If we plug any of these numbers back into the original equation for $H$, we will prove that at these times the hands of the clock are aligned.

$$
\begin{align}
11 * 8{\frac2{11}} + 6 &= 12int(8{\frac{2}{11}}) \\
90 + 6 &= 12 * 8 \\
96 &= 96
\end{align}
$$

When the hour is $8{\frac2{11}}$, the hands line up. Multiplying $\frac2{11}$ by 60 gives us around 10.9 minutes. At around 8:11, the hands are aligned. I won't plug in every number here, but they all work out except for 18. While 18 doesn't work, it is equivalent to 6:00, which we know works. This shows the domain of the equation: [6, 18). (In inequality notation, $6 \le H \lt 18$.)

In conclusion the clock hands align starting at 6:00 and every $1{\frac1{11}}$ hours afterwards. This works out to the following times: 6:00, 7:05, 8:11, 9:16, 10:22, 11:27, 12:33, 1:38, 2:44, 3:49, and 4:55. Five o'clock is the only hour where the hands do not align. After 4:55, they next align at 6:00, restarting the cycle. The times listed are approximate; I rounded the decimal part of the minute up to the nearest whole number.

---

Other comments on the content would be appreciated. This is my first real proof, and I'm curious about its quality.

Sorry about the wall of text; I abbreviated as much I could from the original article, which is linked above.

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of the proof in you post to make it self-contained and not subject to change of an external site (if it goes down, your question is no longer of any value, for example).

Comment: [Related Meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/16736/23353).

Comment: I think it would be simpler to ignore all issues of hours/minutes from this puzzle and instead focus on the angle the clock hands form with the vertical axis.  But, I haven't actually solved the puzzle, so that's just an idea.

Comment: @Arthur By aligned I mean 180º apart, not on top of each other. In this case, both hands form a diameter, not a radius. Solving for 0º apart would be trivially simple, though: just change the 180 to 0. The minute values are the same; subtract 6 from the hour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your solution is fine, but it's more of a discourse than a proof.  What you are doing is modeling a clock.  The content of the 'proof' is just establishing your $D_h - D_m = \theta$ equation (you chose 180 but you could solve for any angle between the hands). It could probably be distilled into about 5 lines of substance.  If your formal definitions of hours and minutes and associated angles are correct, then of course the equation you set up is correct after substitutions (though I think you'd be better off explicitly thinking of this as a modulo situation. The solutions to the equation would be obvious if you make this tweak.)

So, yes it sufficiently proves what you want. But there's a lot of explanation that, depending on the intended audience, might not be necessary.  To prove something rigorously, you don't always need to explain the intuition behind the answer, especially if the problem is straightforward.  After giving your equation, I would have been happy if you just stated the answers with no further discourse.  Since the solutions you give are 12/11 of an hour apart, there clearly can't be any in between solutions.